# Replacing dummy variables with another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a COVID dataset that has dummy variables for each of the counties. That was fairly easy with:

`pf.get_dummies(df, columns=['County'])`

Now I don't necessarily want to return a 1 or 0 value. Instead, I was wondering if I could replace the 1 and instead put in place the values from a column called ['Confirmed Cases']. So for example, there is a dummy variable for San Francisco County and there are 65 confirmed cases on that date, could we replace the '1' with the value 65 from the 'Confirmed' column?

Comment: Can you add sample input/output dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the output of the `get_dummies` by the column you want to keep track of, column-wise:

```py
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['County'])
confirmed_cases_dummies = dummies.multiply(df['Confirmed Cases'], axis=0)
```

If it was 0, it will continue being 0, but in case the value is 1, it will be converted to the number of confirmed cases.